# Cannot turn on WiFi and Bluetooth

Tags: wireless-networking, bluetooth

I have Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 running on Android 4.4.2. I just bought it 3 months ago. It's not rooted (I don't want root it). I also have "Terminal Emulator" (downloaded from Play Store).

I can't turn on WiFi and Bluetooth. MAC address and Bluetooth address also don't show up on settings. When I press the WiFi button (on the quick settings), it turns green for 3-6 seconds, then it turns back to white again (same as Bluetooth button).

Could someone point me what's the cause and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like what happened to my iPhone 4s.  The wireless chip failed and the operating system detected it as if it were a removable device, making it so I had to use cellular for all data.  I was able to get it working again for a while using a hair dryer. People online claim that it "reflows the solder"--there is no way that happens, so I was very skeptical and didn't try it for months, but it did make it work again at least for a few weeks.  There seems to be plenty of people out there who had the same experience as me.  In the end it failed again and each time I tried this trick it worked for shorter and shorter periods of time, to the point where it just wasn't worth it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Make a backup and a hard reset

I had this problem Nexus 5, and only factory reset solved this.

If that does not work, sorry friend, you have a hardware problem, look for an authorized Service.